# Dropdown menu getting cut off at the bottom (wordpress/elementor website)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

I'm building a website with wordpress and elementor.
My main menu turns into a dropdown menu on mobile. the last link of the menu is styled as a red button (sign out). But for some reason it cuts off a little bit at the bottom where the menu ends. Notice how the border radius doesn't show correctly.

I tried adding some bottom margin and padding to that button, but it didn't work.

[screenshot showing the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lfbX.jpg)

Notice that if I modify the menu and place the "contact" link below the "sign out", the button displays well. So the issue only happens with the last item in the menu.

[modified menu with "contact" ad the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gR8iX.jpg)

This is the CSS I used to style the "account" and "sign out" buttons.

```
selector .mobile-link {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  selector .mobile-link {
    display: block;
    width:70%;
    margin:auto;
  }
}

.account-link a {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: #47B47C !important;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.signout-link a {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: #ed5e5e !important;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Please help me solve this issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.